# resolve ${1##*/} in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In `/etc/init.d/functions#_pids_var_run` (which will be there in most Linux distros), i see a local variable initialization like this,

```
local base=${1##*/}
```

what does,

```
${1##*/}
```

get resolved to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In bash scripts, `${varname##pattern}` removes the longest prefix that matches `pattern` from `varname`. For example,

```
foo=bar/baz/qux
echo "${foo##*/}"
```

will print

```
qux
```

In the case of

```
${1##*/}
```

it will remove the longest prefix that matches `*/` from `$1`, which is the first parameter passed to the script/function.

In essence, it is a poor man's `$(basename "$1")`.